# Install React JS on Cent OS

Tags: node.js, linux, reactjs, centos

I am very very new to React JS and have tried to install it on my VPS server that is running Cent OS.

Node.js seems to be working, 
I have build a React project using the following code as a root level user on SSH:

```
npx create-react-app my-react-project
cd my-react-project
npm start
```

but when trying to view in browser I get a blank page (instead of react js default template)?

I see many people install this locally but I haven't found any examples on a hosted VPS, is this something I am doing wrong?

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have ssh access to your VPS, the rest is pretty the same as your local environment.
You can copy/paste your project to your CentOS host and use the following commands in order to run it:

```
cd your_project_folder_which_includes_package_json_file
npm install
npm start
```

Also, if you are using this server as a production host, You should consider getting a production build of your React app on your local env by running `npm run build` and then publishing the `build` folder on your server and serving it using a static file server or using a reverse-proxy such as Nginx as a static server.

Actually [this](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment) page in React documentation does a good job in explaining the details of deploying a React app, I encourage you to take a look at it.

Comment: Got the default React JS page working finally, using my VPS IP Address followed by :3000 in the URL, for example(123.34.65.321:3000). So this now works but when I edit the App.js file text then save and upload, it does not update? any help?